# Matlab : Access timeseries stored in cell array

Tags: matlab, time-series, export-to-csv

I have multiple mat files containing n*1 array.

Each of the cell in these arrays contain a 1 * 1 timeseries (size 6*n) :

[image]

Content of cell 1:1 {1x1 timseries}:

[image]

I am able to see the data using the workspace but when I try to print the data of a cell I only get {1x1 timseries} or error like "Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type." when I do cell.Data.

Do you know how can I access the data inside a cell ? My goal is to xetract the data of each cell to generate a big csv file.

Comment: Please show the actual MATLAB code you use to load a file and access the data.

Comment: For now I access the data using the workspace. The mat file are loaded using load(path_to_file)

Comment: @ILKetchup Please provide a [Minimal,Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: *when I try to print the data of a cell I only get {1x1 timseries} or error like "Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type." when I do cell.Data.* Show us the commands that give these responses.

Answer (score 1):

Use `()` notation to access an item in an array or vector, and use `{}` notation to access the contents. For example:

```
>> cellarray={[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8]}

cellarray =

  1×3 cell array

    {1×3 double}    {1×3 double}    {1×2 double}

>> cellarray(2)

ans =

  1×1 cell array

    {1×3 double}

>> cellarray{2}

ans =

     4     5     6

>> cellarray{1}(2)

ans =

     2
```

I think in your case you want to use something like `cell{Data}`.